# how to insert pages in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have installed timeline in the drupal and enabled it. I created a page callind "mypage.php" that reads data from mysql and creates an xml file. And then I passed it to the java script, that creates time line in the web page, with the support of timeline libraries.

I cannot run this mypage.php in the drupal. how it can be added to drupal? Could any one help in solving this issue.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Why you not using modules instead of php file. I think page module will do best for you.